# MethodNotAllowedHttpException error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i made reply function but it does not work well.. please help me..

it is blade for create reply

```html
<div class="media media__create__comment {{ isset($parentId) ? 'sub' : 'top' }}">

        <div class="media-body">
                <form method="POST" action"{{ route('articles.comments.store', $article->id) }}" class="form-horizontal">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}

                @if(isset($parentId))
                        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ $parentId}}">
                @endif

                <div class"form-group {{ $errors->has('content') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        <textarea name ="content" class="form-control">{{ old('content') }}</textarea>
                        {!! $errors->first('content', '<span class="form-error">:message</span>') !!}
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                전송하기
                </button>
                </div>
        </form>
</div>
</div>
```

and it is controller

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers; //171029

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->middleware('auth');
        }

        public function store(\App\Http\Requests\CommentsRequest $request, \App\Article $article)
        {
                $comment = $article->comments()->create(array_merge($request->all(), ['user_id'=> $request->user()->id] ));

                return redirect(route('articles.show', $article->id) .'#comment_'.$comment->id);
        }
}
```

and finally it is route

```html
Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController', ['only' => ['update', 'destroy']]);

Route::resource('articles.comments', 'CommentsController', ['only' => 'store']);
```

error content is 
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

i searched for 3 hours..
if i use PUT method it does not have error but it changes article's content not reply.. please help me!

thanks to read this

```html
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                         | Name                    | Action                                          | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                           |                         | Closure                                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                    |                         | Closure                                         | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | articles                    | articles.index          | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@index   | web          |
|        | POST      | articles                    | articles.store          | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@store   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | articles/create             | articles.create         | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@create  | web          |
|        | DELETE    | articles/{article}          | articles.destroy        | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@destroy | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | articles/{article}          | articles.update         | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@update  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | articles/{article}          | articles.show           | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@show    | web          |
|        | POST      | articles/{article}/comments | articles.comments.store | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@store   | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | articles/{article}/edit     | articles.edit           | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@edit    | web          |
|        | DELETE    | comments/{comment}          | comments.destroy        | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@destroy | web,auth     |
|        | PUT|PATCH | comments/{comment}          | comments.update         | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@update  | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                       | sessions.create         | App\Http\Controllers\SessionsController@create  | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | login                       | sessions.store          | App\Http\Controllers\SessionsController@store   | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | logout                      | sessions.destroy        | App\Http\Controllers\SessionsController@destroy | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | main                        |                         | Closure                                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | usb                         |                         | App\Http\Controllers\UsbController@index        | web          |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

and it is my route:list ..

Comment: You don't need to send a parameter : `$article->id` using store method.

Comment: In your case, i think you need to define 1 new route like:

`Route::post('articles/{article}/comments', 'CommentsController@store')->name('comment.store');`

and edit `action` attribute in your form.

Comment: everything doesn't work.. same error message :(..

Answer (score 0):

why there is two controller one for just store and the another one for update and delete better you move the store function to `CommentsController` controller.

then change the route to `{{ route('comments.store')}}`.
hope this will help you

Comment: still same errors.. it i change POST to PUT message, it changes article text not make reply..